# how to fill objects with holes

Tags: mesh, vertices, faces, vertex-groups

how can i fill the below file, i only want to fill the selected vertices or faces, but i dont want the hole/circle inside to be filled. when i fill it, the circle also gets fill. i want the fill to be applied only inside leaving a hole in the middle. help please

[image]

Answer (score 5):

You can't create holes without edges connecting to the outer edges, so create these edges and then fill the faces:

[image]

Comment: yes, he can't...but Superman...? That's why you wrote "you can't"...i understand!!!! :D

Comment: @Chris, I'm not sure Superman can even do it, maybe Moonboots though, who knows what he's capable of? This guy is incredible...

Comment: I've heard of a man called Chris who pretends to be as strong as Moonboots, well, maybe in a thousands of years...

Comment: Recently I have bought some Cryptonite…‍♂️

Comment: ok but against Moonboots you'll need garlic and crucifix

Comment: Damn - again, my 3 problems: wrong place, wrong time, wrong items 

Comment: Is Crptonite a knew form of Cryptocurrency?